# How do I restrict certain values in column 2 with the same value in column 1 in SQL?

Tags: mysql

consider the following ERD for a MySQL database:

[image: Entity Relationship Diagram]

the table roles contains all kinds of (website-specific) roles users that are logged in could have. As you can see from the ERD: members can have multiple roles, and roles can have multiple members assigned to them.

The table members is dynamic, new members with custom roles can be made at any time, but the roles table is not. The current set-up of roles is final.

The records inside the roles table look like this:

```
 id  rolename
 1   captain
 2   cabin boy
 3   buccaneer
 4   parrot caretaker
 5   cook
```

Now for the problem: I want members to have certain roles assigned to them, but certain combinations of roles cannot be chosen. For example, a captain can not also be a cabin boy, but he can also be a parrot caretaker. A cook can also be a cabin boy, but not a parrot caretaker.

I have done some research on Google regarding this topic, but I seem to fail in finding the right keywords to actually find usable information to solve this problem. All I seem to find are references and tutorials on how the SQL CHECK works, but not quite THAT in-depth.

Is there a way for me to use MySQL constraints to restrict some combinations from happening? If not, might this problem be solved using triggers or functions? I am generally looking for the most efficient solution to this, it does not necessarily have to be on the database side.

Comment: This is too broad to answer definitively. It depends on how many combinations are permissible, how many combinations aren't permissible and whether either (or both) of those lists are finite.

Comment: I have updated my question with some additional information. The rules table is finite. In the "real" database there are 9 combinations which are not permissable, out of a roles table with 13 records (so 9 out of 169 combinations are not allowed). If the specific restrictions are important to know I will put them in as well.

Comment: No. I think Arth's solution is along the right lines. But it seems you don't need the whitelist, only the blacklist - which I guess will store combinations using the abstract concept of a 'combination_id' and a component member of that prohibited combination. Maybe someone will be kind enough to show you how to query against this, as it's not entirely obvious - or maybe I will... but the sun's just come out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on a few things..

Do you want the database to handle this logic or are you happy to have it at the application level?

If you want the database to handle it, you are probably going to want a trigger.. mysql parses a CHECK constraint but doesn't enforce it.

Either way you'll probably want to store the allowed combinations somewhere. 
For simple cases I'd go for either a black-list or a white-list of other roles for each role depending on numbers. You can store this easily in another table.

Another option is a pre-requisite table, for example to be an admiral you must also be a captain.

Comment: I prefer whichever method is the most efficient. What do you mean by "parses a CHECK constraint but doesn't enforce it"?

Comment: As in it allows you to put one in, but it won't enforce it.. so it's pretty much useless!

Comment: It'll be more efficient in the database I believe, but less flexible. For complex rules that might change, I'd be tempted to put it in the application level.

Comment: Alright well I think I would put it in the database then, but would you show me an example of how you would implement this database-sided?

Comment: With an on update and on insert trigger, check that the attempted change isn't in the blacklist table.. throw an exception if it is; that kind of shiz. I'm not gonna write it for you though :) .. I'd probably put this in the application myself though.